# More calculator decimal help RUBY

Tags: ruby, math, decimal

```
def commission
  puts " What is the percent of commission? "
  commission_percent = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "What is the price of the item sold?"
  price = gets.chomp.to_f
  commission = price * commission_percent
  puts "Your commission is #{'%.0f' % commission.to_f}"
end
```

That's my little commission calculator I am working on. It works perfectly fine, except one thing.

If 7 was my commission_percent, and 5200 was my price, it would return the answer 36400. Is there any way that I could put a decimal dot in the right place?

Comment: Downvoters: please explain yourselves, or withdraw your downvotes. This question may not be interesting for experienced programmers, and demonstrates a couple of beginner misconceptions.  Yet it was researched, a minimum viable program was posted, the expected and actual outputs were explained, it is clear, and useful for fellow beginners. Probably it is also useful to someone designing a language or a math library for beginners. In my opinion it meets the criteria for why SO exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a percentage, multiply by the percentage, and divide by one hundred.(See [Working percent problems](http://www.jamesbrennan.org/algebra/numbers/percents.htm#_Toc535568935)). So

```
commission = commission_percent / 100.0 * price
```

In Ruby, the `.0` converts the calculation to 'floating point' form. This is the simplest way to add a decimal point, but it often introduces rounding errors, so use with care.

Comment: That makes the answer return as zero.

Comment: Good point. I changed the code to use floating point. This isn't the most accurate approach, but it is fine for a simple calculator.